# esp8266 create tcp server but can't receive data

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

I am using arduino ide to program esp8266 (wifi module) and I created a tcp server on the module then i used tcp client tester program to send and receive data .this is the code i am using 
I managed to send data from the module but can't receive any data from my phone , Can anyone help me?
this is the code i am using

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
int i =0;
char ssid[] = "moataz";         
char pass[] = "58295829";  
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

WiFiServer server(1050);

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.begin("moataz", "58295829");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  } 
  Serial.println("connectedd");
  server.begin();
  IPAddress myAddress = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.println(myAddress);
  delay(200);
}

bool alreadyConnected = 0;
void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    if (!alreadyConnected) {
      client.flush();
      Serial.println("We have a new client");
      client.println("Hello, client!");
      alreadyConnected = true;
    }
  }
  if (client.available() > 0) {
    char thisChar = client.read();
    Serial.println("We got data");
    Serial.println(thisChar);
    delay(200);
  }
}
```

Comment: what are you doing on your phone to receive data?

Answer (score 1):

When `WifiClient` is deleted, the connection is closed, then your flag `alreadyConnected` doesnot indicate the connection state.
Your code should works the first time.
In order to accept a TCP connection, send "Hello, client!", read 1 character, close the TCP connection, you can proceed like this :

```
void loop() {
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
        Serial.println("We have a new client");
        client.println("Hello, client!");

        if (client.available() > 0) {
            char thisChar = client.read();
            Serial.println("We got data");
            Serial.println(thisChar);
            delay(200);
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to keep the connection open, you need to keep it outside the loop.
This sample [WiFiTelnetToSerial.ino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiTelnetToSerial/WiFiTelnetToSerial.ino) show how to maintain a list of `WIFIClient`.